# Must I use aria-invalid when I invalidate a field using the HTML5 constraint validation API?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, wai-aria, wcag2.0

As I understand it's not recommended to add duplicate roles to an element:

```
<nav role="navigation"></nav>
```

This is redundant because `nav` tells the screen reader what the semantics of content is already. So far so good.

---

Now I want to invalid a form field. I understand that classical I should transform this:

```
<input type="text" name="username">
```

… into

```
<input type="text" name="username" aria-invalid="true">
```

… after form submission.

---

However, we are using JavaScript and the [HTML5 constraint validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_forms_using_JavaScript) to check the input before sending it to an API. And yes, the input is again tested on the server side.

---

So, let's say I invalidate the field:

```
input.setCustomValidity('This value is invalid');
```

*Do I still need to add `aria-invalid="true"` to the input?*

I'd say no, because it is redundant to what the engine already knows. But I can't find any source describing this scenario explicitly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`aria-invalid`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-invalid) is a hint to screen readers that the field is in error.  As a screen reader user tabs through the `<input>` fields, they will be notified if the field is invalid.

Using `aria-invalid` should be used in conjunction with associating an error message with the field too (via [`aria-describedby`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-describedby)).  If you display an error below the field without associating that error with the field, the screen reader user won't know about it.  If you use `aria-invalid` by itself, the user would not know **why** the field is in error.

So you should have something like:

```
<input type="text" name="username" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="errmsg">
<span id="errmsg">The name you entered cannot be found in our system</span>
```

**Update:**
After further clarification, I see what the OP is asking for now, and the reference to not using duplicate information, such as `<nav role="navigation>`.

With the validation api, the pseudo classes (such as `:invalid`) are set, but screen readers, in general **(*)**, do not know or care about CSS and don't know anything about the pseudo classes.

(**(*)** The only exception is `:before`/`:after`, which can be used in the accessible name calculation as noted in step `2.F.ii` of https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2).

However, in addition to the pseudo class `:invalid` being set, `obj.validity.valid` is also set.  So if that attribute is set, do you also need to use `aria-invalid`?  Or another way to ask, do screen readers know about the `validity.valid` attribute?

I couldn't find any documented references pertaining to screen readers, but from testing, both firefox and chrome surface `validity.valid` to the screen reader (JAWS and NVDA) so they announce the field is invalid.  But Internet Explorer (I'm on Win7 so don't have Edge) and Safari on iOS (I don't have a Mac to test) do **not** surface the field in error.

So to cover all your bases, I would recommend setting `aria-invalid`.  It's great that you don't want to be redundant, but at least being redundant doesn't hurt anything.  It's just extra code or typing you have to do.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. While this is all correct, it doesn't really answer my question: Does the screen reader know, that a field is invalid solely from the Vaildation API? If yes, wouldn't this be sufficient: `<input type="text" name="username" aria-describedby="errmsg">` after validation? Or do I still need to add `aria-invalid="true"`? I'm wondering if the error would be announced twice if the field is marked as `invalid` and `aria-invalid` is present. Hopefully, this make my question a bit clearer.

Comment: What is the validation api?  Unless the api sets the `aria-invalid` attribute, a screen reader will not know the field is invalid.

Comment: See: [HTML5 constraint validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_forms_using_JavaScript). This will make it possible to use the pseudo classes `:valid`, `:invalid`, `:in-range` and `:out-of-range` wich can be targeted by CSS: `input:invalid { border: 1px solid red; }`. Now, the browser seems to know, that a field is valid or invalid. The question is, is this enough for the screen reader to know it as well?

Comment: I see what you're saying now.  I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. This is the answer I was looking for - very helpful.

Comment: This answer is excellent, however it could use some editing such that it answers the question more clearly. Ideally it should provide a clear answer in the first paragraph (as is it provides a marginally related information on top; which should probably be moved further down). The actual answer is in the second to last paragraph and should probably be moved to the top.

Comment: I appreciate the opinion but the FAQ for writing a good answer doesn't mention any of your thoughts - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.  I would recommend that you provide feedback to stackoverflow to update that FAQ,