# Screen Reader and HTML validation

Tags: html, validation, screen-readers, constraint-validation-api

Using HTML5 validation and screen readers, is there a way to make the screen reader read the HTML validation message?

```
<form>
    <input type="email" required="required">
</form>
```

If an invalid email is entered we get an HTML validation message

[image]

Our issue is that the screen reader never reads this validation message, is there a way to make it do so?

Comment: can you try adding `aria-required="true"`

Comment: @IvanS95 - what would i add that too? Theres no way to target this message

Comment: to the input field `<input type="email" aria-required="true">`

Comment: @IvanS595 that will only apply to the input element

Comment: Did you test it? `<input type="text" required aria-required="true">` this might read the message displayed

Comment: @IvanS95 - It does not

Comment: Maybe this article can be of assistance, it seems you would have to create a block of HTML just for the screen reader https://cantina.co/form-errors-screen-readers-can-access/

Comment: Unfortunately not - in that link he is using his own validation and not the built in HTML5 validation message from the browser

Comment: Have you try this? https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA21.html

Comment: @A. Meshu - Yes, i have, unfortunately this only tell the screen reader that the data entered is invalid - it does not read the HTML5 validation message

Comment: since screen reader don't read the browser error message you can COPY it to a container that it will read it from there. https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/Techniques/working-examples/ARIA21/form-alert3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my answer to [Must I use aria-invalid when I invalidate a field using the HTML5 constraint validation API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648772/must-i-use-aria-invalid-when-i-invalidate-a-field-using-the-html5-constraint-val/52651709#52651709)

At first it might seem unrelated but it has to do with using the built in "[constraint validation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#constraints)" API, which it sounds like you're using.  In summary, the internal `object.validity.valid` property is set but only some screen readers are honoring that attribute (the screen reader will announce the field is in error), and even when it's honored, the error message is not properly associated with the field in error so you won't hear the error message.

So currently the answer is, "no", you can't force the screen reader to read the built in error message, which is unfortunate.

To properly associate an error message with a field, see the aforementioned answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply, is it just me or does this seem like an over-site on the browsers' part?

Comment: i'm not sure where the problem is.  if the browser doesn't surface the error message to the accessibility tree, then it's a browser/user agent issue.  if it is surfaced, then it's an assistive technology issue.  either way, i agree that it's an oversight.